# Solving an integral: $\sum \int \frac{\cos(2nt)}{(n+1)^2 }dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

About this equality:

I dont understand how they got to that part of the integral? (the blue part)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(2nt)}{(n+1)^2 }dt = \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dt} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2nt)}{2n(n+1)^2 }dt \Biggr|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

I thought maybe integration by parts, but it doesnt seem fit.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHH its because its sum from $n=0$ that has been changed to $n = 1$ therefore, its the first element in the sum...... am i right?

Comment: Yes, the first term is a constant ($n=0$) and the rest is the result of the integral of the rest of the terms.

Comment: @Alon: You could post that as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered. (If you don't want to do that and/or don't think it would be of any value, you also have the option of deleting the question.)